# R networkD3 color node stroke for radialNetwork()

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

The [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package contains some very nice functions for creating the obvious networks. Different functions have different arguments, so this questions is specifically in regards to the radialNetwork() function. 
Is it possible to have the color of the node stroke change according to a given vector?

The below code creates a the network graph but changing the argument for the node stroke to a vector containing different colors does not work.

```
library(networkD3)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.tree)

## Data
input <- list(number=50)
Data_tree <- data.frame(Start="Class",
                      Asset = sample(c("FI","Equity","Currency","Commodities"),input$number,replace = TRUE),
                      Sub_Asset = sample(c("Asia","Europe","USA","Africa","ME"),input$number,replace = TRUE),
                      Ticker = replicate(input$number,paste0(sample(LETTERS,3),collapse=""))) %>% 
unite(col="pathString",Start,Asset,Sub_Asset,Ticker,sep="-",remove=FALSE) %>%
select(-Start) %>% as.Node(pathDelimiter = "-")



radialNetwork(ToListExplicit(Data_tree, unname = TRUE ), 
           linkColour = "#ccc",
           nodeColour = "#fff",
           nodeStroke = "orange",
           textColour = "#cccccc")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly... [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) does not support that capability. However, you can inject your own JavaScript into that attribute.

For example, if you have a vector of color names in the proper order, you could convert that to a JavaScript array (in the form: `["red", "blue", "green"])` and use the `JS` function from the `htmlwidget` package to build a function to pass through the nodeStroke argument.

```
colorVector <- c("black", "red", "blue", "green", "orange", 
    rep("red", 5), rep("blue", 5), rep("green", 4), rep("orange", 4),
    rep("red", 11), rep("blue", 14), rep("green", 14), rep("orange", 11))

jsarray <- paste0('["', paste(colorVector, collapse = '", "'), '"]')
nodeStrokeJS <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return ', jsarray, '[i]; }'))

radialNetwork(ToListExplicit(Data_tree, unname = TRUE ), 
    linkColour = "#ccc",
    nodeColour = "#fff",
    nodeStroke = nodeStrokeJS,
    textColour = "#cccccc")
```