# R networkD3 diagonalNetwork coloring leaf nodes

Tags: r, networking, networkd3

**Problem description**
I have a data frame which will be clustered and a data frame defining the node colors, like so:

```
# DATA
color.df <- data.frame(
  name = c('node1',"node2","node3"),
  color = c('green','red','blue')
)

data.df <- t(data.frame(
  node1 = c(1,2,3,5),
  node2 = c(4,5,3,5),
  node3 = c(3,3,2,1)
))
```

Then I apply hierarchical clustering and convert it to a radial network:

```
# CLUSTERING
distance.mat <- dist(data.df)
hc <- hclust(distance.mat)
rad <- as.radialNetwork(hc, '')
diagonalNetwork(List = rad)
```

Now I want to color the nodes according to the `color.df`, this is doable when all node colors are known (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992732/r-networkd3-custom-node-color-for-radialnetwork)), however this becomes harder as only the leafs should be colored (obviously my network is much more complex than this example).

**What I tried**
I think the way to go is map the node name to a color, using JS like this:

```
function test(d, i)  { return { "node1" : "green", "node2" : "red", "node3" : "blue" }[d] }
test("node1")
```

I tried to implement this in R:

```
w <- paste('{', paste(color.df %>% 
                        mutate(name = paste0('"', name), color = paste0(color, '"')) %>%
                        unite('x', c(name, color), sep = '" : "' ) %>%
                        .$x, collapse= ', '), '}', collapse = '') 

node.col.func <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return ', w, '[d.name]; }'))
rad <- as.radialNetwork(hc, '')
dn <- diagonalNetwork(List = rad, nodeColour = node.col.func)
```

This does not work however the code itself works, as I hardcode it the nodes get colored:

```
node.col.func <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return ', w, '["node1"]; }'))
```

If I use alert `d.name` will return 'undefined', thus apparently I cannot access the node name here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some puzzling I found that I had to access the node name via `d.data.name` instead of `d.name`. 
So the line:

```
node.col.func <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return ', w, '[d.name]; }'))
```

should be replaced by:

```
node.col.func <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return ', w, '[d.data.name]; }'))
```