# R - JS array in diagonalnetwork

Tags: javascript, r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

My question is with regards to:

[R networkD3 color node stroke for radialNetwork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568997/r-networkd3-color-node-stroke-for-radialnetwork)

Whenever I create and use a colour vector (context given in link's answer), the `diagonalNetwork()` distributes the node colours incorrectly.

Is there any way to know how the `diagonalNetwork()` rearranges the data input into it? The network labels and structure are correct. Only the colours are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors are applied per level, and then in the order the data was originally. In this example, the colors are ordered so that the root is black, the provinces are red, and the cities are blue.

```
library(networkD3)

CanadaPC <- list(name = "Canada", children = 
                   list(list(name = "Newfoundland",
                             children = list(list(name = "St. John's"))),
                        list(name = "PEI",
                             children = list(list(name = "Charlottetown"))),
                        list(name = "Nova Scotia",
                             children = list(list(name = "Halifax"))),
                        list(name = "New Brunswick",
                             children = list(list(name = "Fredericton"))),
                        list(name = "Quebec",
                             children = list(list(name = "Montreal"),
                                             list(name = "Quebec City"))),
                        list(name = "Ontario",
                             children = list(list(name = "Toronto"),
                                             list(name = "Ottawa"))),
                        list(name = "Manitoba",
                             children = list(list(name = "Winnipeg"))),
                        list(name = "Saskatchewan",
                             children = list(list(name = "Regina"))),
                        list(name = "Nunavuet",
                             children = list(list(name = "Iqaluit"))),
                        list(name = "NWT",
                             children = list(list(name = "Yellowknife"))),
                        list(name = "Alberta",
                             children = list(list(name = "Edmonton"))),
                        list(name = "British Columbia",
                             children = list(list(name = "Victoria"),
                                             list(name = "Vancouver"))),
                        list(name = "Yukon",
                             children = list(list(name = "Whitehorse")))
                   ))

colorVector <- c("black", rep("red", 13), rep("blue", 16))

jsarray <- paste0('["', paste(colorVector, collapse = '", "'), '"]')
nodeStrokeJS <- JS(paste0('function(d, i) { return ', jsarray, '[i]; }'))

diagonalNetwork(List = CanadaPC, nodeStroke = nodeStrokeJS)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! To re-arrange my data by tree "depth", I did the following:    asdf<-rbind(1:length(CEO_depth),CEO_depth)
abcd<-split(asdf[1,1:dim(asdf)[2]],asdf[2,1:dim(asdf)[2]])

diagindex<-c()

for (n5 in 1:length(abcd)){
qwer<-unlist(abcd[n5])
for (n6 in 1:length(unlist(qwer))){
diagindex<-rbind(diagindex,as.numeric(as.character(unlist(qwer)[n6])))
}
}

colour3<-colour2[diagindex]

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how to format stack overflow comments.